# Update one specific file on any action with head revision

Tags: svn, revisions, svn-propset

i want to have on file, that contains the HEAD revision of the **whole** project.

i know, that i can do that with `svn propset`.
but the problem of this is, if the file is not changed, the value of the revision will, indeed, stay the same.

how can i achieve that this file is always updated with the HEAD revision.
no matter which file was modified.

is that even possible to achieve?

Comment: Why you want such file? For which business-task?

Comment: this will be a summary file that'll contains some information of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this inside svn repository (unless you change this specific file on each commit, not very desirable).

However there is a small tool called **svnversion** (part of subversion commandline). By calling this inside your workingcopy (or pointing to it via argument) it returns the revision number of this specific workingcopy.

I suggest you call this tool after each update and write the result into a (svn ignored) textfile inside your workingcopy.

TortoiseSVN has client-side hookscripts (Post-Update-Hook) which can further automate this for you.

Keep in mind that svnversion returns more than just a single number, if you have sparse checkout, modified or switched working copies

Comment: after some research, i know now how to use your suggestion. but i wonder if something like this is available for netbeans...

Comment: I am not expert for netbeans, but I am sure there are ant or maven task out there you can easily modify to insert these actions into a pre-build step